# Redirect django view to bokeh server startet with subprocess on webserver

Tags: python, django, server, bokeh, panel

I have a Django web server deployed on an AWS machine. I don't want to build a Django bokeh app. All I want to do is to display my dashboard which runs on the bokeh server in an HTML file which I can reach through an URL of my website.

In my views.py I start the bokeh server with:

```
import os
print("debug1")
os.system("panel serve /opt/bitnami/projects/blog/EnviAI/scripts/visz_pn_ssm_1.py")
print("debug2")
script = server_document("http://localhost:5006/visz_pn_ssm_1")
return render(request, 'ssm_results.html', {'script' : script})
```

In my console, I can see that the server is started successfully. The debug1 print is also printed. The problem I have is the code stops here and do nothing until I cancel the bokeh server. The debug2 statement is printed as I cancel the bokeh server. The problem is that the code will never get to the point that the return redirect to the actual bokeh server because I have to kill them?! What can I do?

EDIT:
Solve the problem with @sudden_appearance subprocess.Popen() solution.

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen(["panel", "serve","--show","/opt/bitnami/projects/blog/EnviAI/scripts/visz_pn_ssm_1.py", "--log-level", "debug"])
```

Comment: Do you wan't your `os.system(...)` part to run py script in background? Now your code stops until `os.system(...)` proccess is completed

Comment: No, but I don't know another way to start the bokeh server :). Is there a function I can call to start the server? I only know the `bokeh serve script.py` method...

Comment: What I mean is that your script.py is running until 3rd line. There it waits for `os.system()` function to complete and blocks the code. You call `panel serve script.py` which runs until not stopped

Comment: Yes I know that's my question ;D What is a workaround to get the server running and the code in views.py at the same time?

Comment: SImple way is to use [`subprocess.Popen(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead of `os.system(...)`. But the best and right way is to launch 2 different processes via docker(-compose) or similar things